# Number of $n$-tuples with bounded product

Tags: combinatorics

Given $M$ a positive integer, how to find the number of $n$-tuples of positive integers whose product is no larger than $M$? And what if there is a further constraint that every integer in the $n$-tuple is in the range $[a,b]$? Any asymptotically closed lower bound is good enough.

I think it might be a well-studied problem, but I don't know where to start searching. Any references on this or similar problems are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is $(2, 3)$ different from $(3, 2)$? And is $(1, 1, 3)$ allowed (ones)? If the answer to both is no then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_partition is interesting.

Comment: @orlp 'Tuple' means the order is taken into consideration. And ones are positive integers so they are allowed. But the wiki page is still an awesome point to start, thank you!

Comment: For 4-tuples see https://oeis.org/A007426 for references. This is for numbers whose product is exactly $M$, sum over these to get your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the problem of $d_k(n)$, the number of positive integer solutions to $x_1\cdots x_k = n$. This is gives:

$$d_k(n) = \sum_{x|n} d_{k-1}(n/x)$$

$$d_1(n) = 1$$

If $n = p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$ we also have $\displaystyle d_k(n) = \prod_i \binom{k-1+e_i}{k-1}.$

Your problem is finding bounds on $D_k(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n \leq x}d_k(n)$. This is what's known as the [Piltz divisor problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function#Piltz_divisor_problem), and there is indeed a lot of literature on this problem.