# Find number of $n$-tuples of naturals greater than 1 such that their product is at most $K$.

Tags: combinatorics

I have to find the number of different solutions to: $$\begin{align}0<\prod_{i=1}^nk_i\leqslant K\in\Bbb N,\ k_i \in \Bbb N^{+}\setminus\{1\}&\  \forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\},\end{align}$$

It seems trivial to enumerate this in a recursive manner as ${k_i}_\max=\frac{K}{2^{n-1}}$. However, I would like to get the number of different solutions as a function of $K$ and $n$? Any hints or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I think you can find some recursion for the function say $f(K,n)$.

probably, $f(K,n)=\sum_{i=2}^{[K/2]} f([\frac{k}{i}],n-1)$
where $[x]$ denote the floor function.

Comment: Is $k_i\in\Bbb N$? Because you wrote it in the title, but not in the body.

Comment: Have you tried prime factoring if the number is composite?

Comment: Yes, $k_i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Your question becomes: In how many different ways can we group the prime factors, right?

Comment: $k_i$ does not have to be prime.

Comment: whose prime factors do you mean?

Comment: @Yesit'sme, we can decompose every composite $k_i$ and the problem can boil down to prime decomposition of $K$.  When we group them, or make some quasi partition, any of the group can be $k_i$ and, of course, there would be strictly less than $n$ groups, you can have ordered pairs, and so on...

Comment: @Cheesecake well,the primes need to necessarily be of K.so,in case we use that idea,we have to work with all the primes less than or equal to K.

Comment: This may be an answer to my question. However, I'm not sure that the answer is applicable when $k_i \geq 2$. Probably with some modifications: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440681/number-of-n-tuples-with-bounded-product?rq=1

Comment: I implemented the recursive function mentioned above in Julia as 
`prodcount(n, K) = n > 0 ? sum(Int64[prodcount(n-1, K/m) for m = 2:K÷2^(n-1)]) : 1`. 

The output for $1 \leq n \leq 5$ and $1 \leq K \leq 50$ looks something like:
 0  0  0  1  1  3  3  5  6  8  8  12  …  56  58  60  62  69  69  71  73  79
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   4     38  38  38  38  50  50  50  50  59
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0      9   9   9   9  15  15  15  15  19
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0      1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all the useful comments from above, I devised an answer. The number of n
-tuples of naturals greater than 1 such that their product is at most K equals to:

\begin{equation}
f(K, n) = \sum_{k=2}^{\lfloor \frac{K}{2^{n-1}}\rfloor} f(\lfloor \frac{K}{k} \rfloor, n - 1)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
f(K, 0) = 1
\end{equation}

Similarly, in the previous question: [Number of $n$-tuples with bounded product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440681/number-of-n-tuples-with-bounded-product?rq=1) in which naturals greater or equal 1 are considered the count is obtained recursively as well. This corresponds to divisor summatory function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function. However, in this case naturals in tuples are greater than one.